# fsolve/fzero: No solution found, appears regular

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, solver, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to do the following algorithm using fsolve or fzero:

```
K5=8.37e-2
P=1

Choose an A
    S2=(4*K5/A)^(2/3)
    S6=3*S2
    S8=4*S2

    SO2 = (5*P)/149 - (101*S2)/149 - (293*S6)/149 - (389*S8)/149
    H2O = (40*P)/149 + (556*S2)/447 + (636*S6)/149 + (2584*S8)/447
    H2S = 2*SO2

    newA = (H2O)^2/(SO2)^3

Repeat until newA=oldA
```

The main thing to solve is `K5=1/4 * A * S2^3/2`.  It is from this that `S2` is calculated in the first place.

So here is what I did in Matlab:

```
function MultipleNLEexample
clear, clc, format short g, format compact

Aguess = 300000; % initial guess

options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter','TolFun',[1e-9],'TolX',[1e-9]); % Option to display output
xsolv=fsolve(@MNLEfun,Aguess,options); 

[~,ans]=MNLEfun(xsolv)

%- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
function varargout = MNLEfun(A); 
    K5 = 8.37e-2;

    S2 = (4*K5/A)^(2/3);
    S6 = 3*S2;
    S8 = 4*S2;

    P=1; %atm

    SO2 = (5*P)/149 - (101*S2)/149 - (293*S6)/149 - (389*S8)/149;
    H2O = (40*P)/149 + (556*S2)/447 + (636*S6)/149 + (2584*S8)/447;
    newA=H2O^2/SO2^3;
    fx=1/4*newA*S2^(3/2)-K5;

    varargout{1} = fx;
    if nargout>1
        H2S = 2*SO2;
        varargout{2} = ((2*S2+6*S6+8*S8)/(2*S2+6*S6+8*S8+H2S+SO2)*100);
    end
```

I cannot get my code to run, I get the following error:
No solution found.

fsolve stopped because the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient,
but the vector of function values is not near zero as measured by the
selected value of the function tolerance.

I have tried setting the tolerances as low as `1e-20` but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your system is set up, it is actually convenient to plot it and observe its behavior. I vectorized your function and plotted`f(x) = MLNEfun(x)-x`, where the output of `MLNE(x)` is `newA`. Effectively, you are interested in a *fixed point* of your system.

What I observe is this:

[image: singularity]

There is a singularity, and a root crossing, at A ~ 3800. We can use `fzero` since it is a bracketed root solver, and give it very tight bounds on the solution `fzero(@(x)MLNEfun(x)-x, [3824,3825])` which produces `3.8243e+03`. This is a couple order of magnitudes from your starting guess. There is no solution to your system near ~3e5.

**Update** 
In my haste, I failed to zoom in on the plot, which shows another (well-behaved) root at 1.3294e+04. It is up to you to decide which is the physically meaningful one(s). Everything I say below still applies. Just start your guess near the solution you're interested in.

**In response to comment**
Since you want to perform this for varying values of `K`, then your best bet is to stick with `fzero` so long as you are solving for one variable, instead of `fsolve`. The reason behind this is that `fsolve` uses variants of Newton's method, which are not bracketed and will struggle to find solutions at singular points like this. `fzero` on the other hand, uses Brent's method which is guaranteed to find a root (if it exists) within a bracket. It is also much more well behaved near singular points.

MATLAB's implementation of `fzero` also searches for a bracketing interval before carrying out Brent's method. So, if you provide a single starting guess sufficiently close to the root, it should find it for you. Sample output from `fzero` below:

```
fzero(@(x)MLNEfun(x)-x, 3000, optimset('display', 'iter'))

Search for an interval around 3000 containing a sign change:
 Func-count    a          f(a)             b          f(b)        Procedure
    1            3000       -616789          3000       -616789   initial interval
    3         2915.15       -433170       3084.85       -905801   search
    5            2880       -377057          3120  -1.07362e+06   search
    7         2830.29       -311972       3169.71  -1.38274e+06   search
    9            2760       -241524          3240  -2.03722e+06   search
   11         2660.59       -171701       3339.41  -3.80346e+06   search
   13            2520       -109658          3480  -1.16164e+07   search
   15         2321.18      -61340.4       3678.82   -1.7387e+08   search
   17            2040      -29142.6          3960   2.52373e+08   search

Search for a zero in the interval [2040, 3960]:
 Func-count    x          f(x)             Procedure
   17            2040      -29142.6        initial
   18         2040.22      -29158.9        interpolation
   19         3000.11       -617085        bisection
   20         3480.06  -1.16224e+07        bisection
   21            3960   2.52373e+08        bisection
   22         3720.03  -4.83826e+08        interpolation
....
   87         3824.32  -5.46204e+48        bisection
   88         3824.32   1.03576e+50        bisection
   89         3824.32   1.03576e+50        interpolation

Current point x may be near a singular point. The interval [2040, 3960] 
reduced to the requested tolerance and the function changes sign in the interval,
but f(x) increased in magnitude as the interval reduced.

ans =

   3.8243e+03
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. The value for K5 is actually also changing. I.e. I will get K5 at the current point, use the algorithm to find H2S, then go on with all other stuff there is to do. On the next run, I will have a new K5 again. Because of this, the bracketing might need to change, since K5=f(T), and it is quite sensitive to T, the larger T gets. I will quickly check the domain of K5

Comment: It seems safe to say K5 will vary between 0.012893 and 0.27503

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your commend and after looking at your system in a little more detail.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you mean. I'm trying to vectorize the function now, but struggling a little bit.  Also, why is it needed to subtract x from MLNEfun(x)?

Comment: You don't need to vectorize your function. I just did it for the plotting. The reason I subtract `x` from `MLNEfun` is because I changed the definition a bit. Instead of returning K5, I returned `Anew`. That way you can think of it like this: what value of `A`, can I supply to my function and get the same `A` back out. In other words, we are solving `f(x)=x`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29 for details.

Comment: I really must be very tired, because I keep getting `Undefined function 'MLNEfun' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

Comment: Hahah! Found it! MNLE vs MLNE